# Cocos2d-x 3.17 : Best way to make loading / progress bar

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-x

// TYPE 1

```
auto loadingbar = ui::LoadingBar::create("loadingbar.png");
    loadingbar->setPosition(winSize/2);
    loadingbar->setPercent(0);
    this->addChild(loadingbar);
    this->schedule([=](float delta){
        float percent = loadingbar->getPercent();
        percent++;
        loadingbar->setPercent(percent);
        if (percent>=100.0f) {
            this->unschedule("updateLoadingBar");
        }
    }, 0.1f, "updateLoadingBar");
```

// TYPE 2

```
auto timerBG = Sprite::create("loadingbar.png");
    auto loadingBar = ProgressTimer::create(timerBG);
    loadingBar->setPosition(winSize/2);
    loadingBar->setType( ProgressTimerType::BAR );
    loadingBar->setAnchorPoint( Vec2( 0.0, 0.0 ) );
    loadingBar->setBarChangeRate( Vec2( 1,0 ) );
    loadingBar->setMidpoint( Vec2( 0.0, 0.0 ) );
    loadingBar->setPercentage( 34 );
    this->addChild( loadingBar, 2);

    auto prog = ProgressFromTo::create(2.0, 20, 100);

    loadingBar->runAction(prog);
```

Out of above 2, which is the best way to make loading progress ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the original source for the UI LoadingBar class and it has some interesting methods you can use out of the box:

You can create the bar with different textures, texts and set the percentage:

```
LoadingBar* LoadingBar::create(const std::string &textureName, float percentage)
```

You can change the direction of the bar, this can be useful if you decide to change the design of your loading scene once it has been implemented:

```
void LoadingBar::setDirection(cocos2d::ui::LoadingBar::Direction direction)
```

You can replace the texture on the fly, imagine you want to change the image as the loading progresses like some games do:

```
void LoadingBar::loadTexture(SpriteFrame* spriteframe)
```

Also, this inherits from UI `Widget` which like all UI elements will handle things like scaling for you.

In terms of performance, though, I don't think it makes too much difference for a loading bar so if you just want a really simple one, your second option, although less flexible could be used too.